# The configuration of my kotlin multiplatform project is not setting

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-multiplatform-mobile

I crated a KMM project and started coding few days back. But when I reopened the project today I am unable to set the configuration to run it. Also I am not able to debug the issue. Does anyone know how to set the config?

[image]

Comment: did your project sync succeed, with no errors? If yes, try ordinary AS stuff: e.g. invalidate caches, remove `%USERPROFILE%\.gradle\`

Comment: I tried this but it does not work

Comment: The module should be there unless gradle config failed. Need to see your project and `androidApp` `build.gradle.kts`. Also check out warnings and errors in `Build` tab, even when sync succeed there might be some